# the tomcat throw a IllegalArgumentException

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

the tomcat throw the exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The IPv6 address contains an embedded IPv4 address at an invalid location.
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.readHostIPv6(HttpParser.java:804)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.Host.parse(Host.java:70)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.Host.parse(Host.java:40)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.parseHost(AbstractProcessor.java:277)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.prepareRequest(Http11Processor.java:1203)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:776)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How can I solve this problem，please help me.Thank you in advance

> **note**: the springboot version is '1.5.15.BUILD-SNAPSHOT' and the tomcat version is '8.5.32' which is embedded in springboot,the window server version is 2008！

Comment: You can use "server.address" in your "application.properties" file to control the network address.